# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Upon adding the following where condition :

```
->whereBetween('p.created_at', [
                Carbon::parse('c.created_at')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
                Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
```

I receive this error :

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (c.created_at) at
>   position 8 (d): Double timezone specification

Comment: What is in `c.created_at`? Can you add this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `c.created_at` is a column from a joined table in your query.. where between expects the second parameter to be an array of objects, but `c.created_at` cannot be included just like that there..

You will have to do a full query in order to select that column only.. or just use a raw query like this:

```
->whereRaw('p.created_at between c.created_at and ?', [ now()->endOfDay() ])
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the date of c.created_at only from start of day. This will only get the time also of c.created_at

Comment: @abdallah, or use `date(c.created_at)` in the raw query, which will compare just the dates excluding the time.